# Howto self-restart a service when network link goes down?

Tags: networking, script, services

I have a VPN using L2P/IPsec. A service I created establishes the ppp0 interface and tunnel. The service basically executes a shell script that does all the work.

I can start/stop the service and all works well. However, intermittently - but only after a few days - the ppp0 link goes down and yet the service is shown as "Active running". "Keep-Alives" are being sent every minute. I probably have got something wrong with the service unit file.

Until I can diagnose and resolve why ppp0 is going down, how best could I modify my fileset so that the service 'self-restarts' if and when the ppp0 link goes down.

## /etc/systemd/system/vpn-connect.service

```
[Service]
Environment=PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
WorkingDirectory=/tmp
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/daz/VPN/vpn-connect.sh
# kill any zombie process for the vpn-connect script
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "ps -ef | grep 'vpn-connect' | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs -r kill -9"
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=inherit
TimeoutStopSec=60

[Unit]
Description=IPsec L2TP tunner
After=network-online.target
#StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=homeassistant.service
```

## vpn-connect.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

ppp0_up() {
  UP=0
  DOWN=1
  ip link show ppp0 >/dev/null 2>&1 && return $UP || return $DOWN
}

# SHUTDOWN IF SYSTEMD SENDS SIGTERM

shutdown_func() {
  echo "d myvpn" > /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control
  ipsec down myvpn
  while ppp0_up ; do
          echo "Waiting for ppp0 to go down ..."
          sleep 5
  done
  echo "$0: ppp0/myvpn now down"
}

# Run shutdown_func when terminated

trap 'shutdown_func' SIGTERM

# CONNECT - secrets removed replaced with asterisk

VPN_SERVER_IP=*
VPN_IPSEC_PSK=*
VPN_USER=*
VPN_PASSWORD=*

# Check for root

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]] ; then
  echo "$0: Must be run as ROOT"
  exit 1
fi

# Create ipsec/L2TP config files
 
echo "
### Creating ipsec connections file ..."
cat > /etc/ipsec.conf <<EOF
config setup

conn %default
  ikelifetime=60m
  keylife=20m
  rekeymargin=3m
  keyingtries=1
  keyexchange=ikev1
  authby=secret
  ike=aes128-sha1-modp2048!
  esp=aes128-sha1-modp2048!

conn myvpn
  keyexchange=ikev1
  left=%defaultroute
  auto=add
  authby=secret
  type=transport
  leftprotoport=17/1701
  rightprotoport=17/1701
  right=$VPN_SERVER_IP
EOF

echo "
### Creating PSK file ..."
cat > /etc/ipsec.secrets <<EOF
: PSK "$VPN_IPSEC_PSK"
EOF
chmod 600 /etc/ipsec.secrets

echo "
### Creating xl2tpd config file ..."
cat > /etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf <<EOF
[lac myvpn]
lns = $VPN_SERVER_IP
ppp debug = yes
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.client
length bit = yes
EOF

echo "
### Creating PPP client file ..."
cat > /etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.client <<EOF
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
refuse-eap
require-chap
noccp
noauth
mtu 1280
mru 1280
noipdefault
defaultroute
usepeerdns
connect-delay 5000
name $VPN_USER
password $VPN_PASSWORD
EOF


# Start

chmod 600 /etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.client

echo "
### Creating control file ..."
mkdir -p /var/run/xl2tpd
touch /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control

echo "
### Restarting services ..."
service strongswan restart
service xl2tpd restart

echo "
### Bringing up connection ..."
ipsec up myvpn
echo "c myvpn" > /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control
while ! ppp0_up ; do
        echo "waiting for ppp0 ..."
        sleep 5
done

echo "
### DONE !!"

# All done, print config to stdout and keep this process running

ifconfig # ??
sleep infinity
```

Comment: There is a `[Service]` section missed in your Unit file. Don't like to use `killall` with `ExecStartPre=`?

Comment: Does your shell script exit when the network link goes down?

Comment: Why to keep the process running with 'sleep infinity'`? Usually there is no need to sleep for nothing.

Comment: [Service] was in. Just a cut n paste error. No, it doesn't end when network goes down. Sleep infinity allows SIGTERM to be trapped and the script to then gracefully bring down the connection. With that all said, does anyone else reading, wish to provide help with the OP please.

Comment: Seems your script is doing too much that should be done by systemd. The script could monitor the network link and exit with error if it goes down. Restart is done by systemd. Instead of sleeping infinty I would have a look at `type=oneshot` with `RemainAfterExit=yes`. Graceful shutdown is managed by systemd, and so on.

Comment: I do not concur - at all. oneshot reports state as 'activating' until the script had exited , consequent on which the state is 'inactive' or 'active' if RemainAfterExit is set.  So if the script monitors and ends as you say then i would have a service that is active without the associated ppp0 interface and tunnel , up. That's illogical and wrong. In think I need to post to  another forum.

Comment: OK, my comment is a bit confusing. Instead of sleeping infinity I would successful exit with Type=oneshot and RemainAfterExit. I can't see any difference. The script is just doing nothing until SIGTERM to bring down the connection. But that is better done by systemd with ExecStop or ExecStopPost. If the script is monitoring the connection then that is another (additional) condition and it has to stay in the background for this until the connection fails and the script exit with error. Automatic restarting it is very simple with systemd.

Comment: Ah I see. Ok, that makes sense. Indeed, I have modified the script such that it writes BASHPID to /var/run/vpn-connect.pid. On each ExecStop it kills the process in vpn-connect.pid and brings down any existing ppp0 interface. This ensures any zombie process is terminated. ExecStart it then waits until ppp0 is down before bringing it up again and looping (sleep 10) until the interface is down. Ideally this never happens so this is more of a watchdog. The service file is simple (not oneshot) so that the script is not blocking.